Github pages has set a custom domain as standard and I can't reset it
I've set a custom domain in one repository months ago, now for some reason a completely unrelated repository keeps using the custom domain as it's default. I've tried setting a new cname, but the domain appears in place of the custom ".github.io". How can I reset it back to ".github.io"?
this is a print of how it appears

Do you mean that your repo username.github.io has a custom domain, say, mydomain.com, and now your other repo shows up at mydomain.com/otherrepo instead of username.github.io/otherrepo?

not exactly, it's like the older repo appears as mydomain.com and this as mydomain.otherepo without the github.io, it literally replaced the default

I don't understand: in mydomain.otherrepo, the top-level domain would be otherrepo, but that doesn't make sense?
